# Naming an object property with a function expression seems as if it should be impossible. But it compiles

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

How does this JavaScript compile? It looks wrong, even to me, and I once programmed in perl. When I enter this in the Google Chrome console:

```
window[function () {}] = 42;
>>> 42
```

Nothing exploded. How?

I shrugged it off. Thinking that property could clearly not have been assigned, or if it were it should at least have been instantly destroyed. But lo:

```
window[function () {}]
>>> 42
```

Comment: Looks like sci-fi but... I have experienced also weird things like printing an array which because of prototypical contamination had a function inside... and that function got printed too. The implementation of the function. I stay around out of curiosity...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This actually an example of type coercion where javscript wants a string to use as a property name so it calls `.toString()` on the function definition.

When you do `window[function () {}]`, javascript calls `function () {}.toString()` and gets the string `"function () {}"` which becomes the property name.

You can see that by doing `alert(function () {});`

So, thus you end up with a property `window["function () {}"]`.

Try this sequence to illustrate:

```
window[function () {x=1;}] = 42;
alert(window["function () {x=1;}"]);    // alerts 42
```

Comment: Interesting to know, that the `toString` function on functions is adding a space between the function´s name and the parens. `window[function() {}]` becomes `window["function () {}"]`.

Comment: @Amberlamps - the function source is likely stored and used with `.toString()`, but the definition part is apparently reconstituted in a particular form.

Comment: Interesting, this is why I got a function printed inside of a div.